# Does drinking milk at night help one to sleep better and absorb more calcium?

Tags: milk

According to this [article](http://gethealthinformations.com/at-night-the-best-time-to-drink-milk-369729/), it is noted that the best time to drink milk is at night.

> In this discussion, dr. Sjoekri Rini replied that the milk contains the amino acid tryptophan, a precursor to the neurotransmitter serotonin which is useful. The nature of this alone is calming neurotransmitter that helps the sleep process more quickly.
>
> Meanwhile, according to nutritionists Stikes Husada Banjarbaru Borneo, Nor Hasanah, adding that the calcium in milk is one of the best nutrients for maintaining bone health as calcium is more readily absorbed. So that, for the most milk should be consumed at night. In the evening, osteoclasts, or cells of the bone destruction does not work. In addition, our activities in the evening is also limited so that the calcium of milk will be absorbed optimally.

Comment: A poorly-translated [scraper site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scraper_site)? This is insufficiently notable.

Comment: The original appears to be [here](http://helthy-planet.blogspot.com/2012/07/night-best-time-to-drink-milk.html).